# Is there any lightweight real-world example when there are no alternatives to constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Is there any lightweight real-world example when there are no alternatives for `constexpr`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. What do you mean by "alternatives for `constexpr`?"

Comment: @NicolBolas "alternatives for `constexpr`" - it's conditionally, of course. Let's say, `mov`, `cmp` and `jump` it's enough to develop any software without any OOP, - it's firstly. And any theoretical principles become more clear with examples of practical use of it.

Answer (score 1):

A function used in a `case` would have to be `constexpr`. Example:

```
switch(hashfunc(input)) {
case hashfunc("hello"):
    std::cout << "world\n";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the following code is compiled with optimizations:

```
struct A { 
    int a_; 
    A(int a) : a_(a) {}
};

struct B { 
    int a_; 
    constexpr B(int a) : a_(a) {}
};

A a{1};
B b{1};
```

`gcc` generates code that invokes `A` constructor for global variable `a` because `A` constructor is not `constexpr`. Whereas there is no call to `B` constructor to initialize `b` variable.

`clang`, however, elides the call to the constructor in both cases.

The [generated code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/JuDAJE).